# No module named registro.forms in my own local django server [edited]

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

im setting Django Server in my Ubuntu machine, apache/wsgi, but im getting a error in my view:
was **No module named registro.forms**  now after some code in my wsgi is **No module name forms**

```
#registro.views

from registro.forms import ComercioForm
```

In my laptop is running but not in my server machine
django is running
all database table are syncd

## WSGI

```
#path /srv/www/project/apache/django.wsgi

import is, sys

sys.path.insert(0,'/srv/www')
sys.path.insert(0,'/srv/www/project')
sys.path.insert(0,'/srv/www/') #testing
sys.path.insert(0,'/srv/www/project/') #testing

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='project.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

## httpd.conf

```
#path /srv/www/project/apache/

Alias /media/ "/srv/www/project/public/admin_tools"

<Directory "/srv/www/project/public/admin_tools">
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias "/srv/www/project/apache/django.wsgi"

<Directory "/srv/www/project/apache">
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

## project

```
#path /etc/apache2/sites-available

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/project

    <Directory /srv/www/project>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIDeamonProcess project processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup project

    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/project/apache/django.wsgi

</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the "registro"-application in your Django-Path. For an example how to fix it, [see here](http://codespatter.com/2009/04/10/how-to-add-locations-to-python-path-for-reusable-django-apps/)
.